# How can I run a python script from within Kodi?

Tags: python, customization, kodi

If I want to make a button in Kodi's menu and run a local python script upon clicking it, what's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_path = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('insert path here to file you want to run'))
xbmc.executebuiltin("XBMC.RunScript("+file_path+")")

Very late reply but saw no one else had answered so though i'd put in just in case

Comment: it ended up being an environment/permissions issue but I accepted it as answered because you're technically correct :)